# How can PHP do centralized curl_multi requests?

Tags: php, curl, ipc, curl-multi

I currently have a website written in PHP, utilizing the curl_multi for polling external APIs. The server forks child processes to standalone from web requests and is working well, but it is somewhat limited to a per process basis.

Occasionally it hit bandwidth bottlenecks and needs a better centralized queuing logic.

I am currently trying PHP IPC with a standalone background process to handle all the outgoing requests, but was stuck in things that, normally said, is not likely to be catered by casual programmers. Says, garbage collection, inter-process exception handling, request-response matching... and etc. Am I going the wrong way?

Is there a common practise (implementation theory) out there, or even libraries I could make use of?

**EDIT**

Using localhost TCP/IP communication would double the stress of the local trafic, which is definitely not a good approach.

I am currently working on IPC message queue with some home-brew protocol... not looking right at all. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You have so many clients that consume all your resources?

Comment: @Martin This is part of the situation, to solve this I must create some kind of connection manager. My question is how should I make one, a local http proxy might help but that will consume 2x of the traffic on the local network, and that is not very effective...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several different things to distinguish here:

- jobs : you have N jobs to process. Executed tasks can crash or hang, in any way all jobs should be proceeded without any data loss.
- resources : you are processing your jobs in a single machine and/or in a single connection, so you need to take care of your cpu and bandwith.
- synchronization : if you have interactions between your processes, you need to share information, taking care of concurrent data access.

---

## Keep control on resources

[image: Everybody wants to get into the bus...]

### Everybody want to get into the bus...

Because there is no built-in threads in PHP, we will need to simulate *mutexes*. The principle is quite simple:

<kbd>1</kbd> All jobs are put in a queue

<kbd>2</kbd> There is N resources available and no more in a *pool*

<kbd>3</kbd> We iterate the queue (a `while` on each job)

<kbd>4</kbd> Before execution, job asks for a resource in the pool

<kbd>5</kbd> If there is available resources, job is executed

<kbd>6</kbd> If there is no more resources, pool hangs until a job has finished or is considered dead

[image: How does Mutex work?]

### How to do that in PHP?

To proceed, we have several possibilities but the principle is the same:

We have 2 programs:

- There is a **process launcher** that will launch no more than N tasks simultaneously.
- There is a **process child**, it represents a `thread's context`

### How can look a process launcher?

The process launcher knows how many tasks should be run, and run them without taking care of their result. It only control their execution (a process starts, finishes, or hangs, and N are already running).

<kbd>PHP</kbd> I give you **the idea** here, I'll give you usable examples later:

```
<?php
// launcher.php

require_once("ProcessesPool.php");

// The label identifies your process pool, it should be unique for your process launcher and your process children
$multi = new ProcessesPool($label = 'test');

// Initialize a new pool (creates the right directory or file, cleans a database or whatever you want)
// 10 is the maximum number of simultaneously run processes
if ($multi->create($max = '10') == false)
{
    echo "Pool creation failed ...\n";
    exit();
}

// We need to launch N processes, stored in $count
$count = 100; // maybe count($jobs)

// We execute all process, one by one
for ($i = 0; ($i < $count); $i++)
{
    // The waitForResources method looks for how many processes are already run,
    // and hangs until a resource is free or the maximum execution time is reached.
    $ret = $multi->waitForResource($timeout = 10, $interval = 500000);
    if ($ret)
    {
        // A resource is free, so we can run a new process
        echo "Execute new process: $i\n";
        exec("/usr/bin/php ./child.php $i > /dev/null &");
    }
    else
    {
        // Timeout is reached, we consider all children as dead and we  kill them.
        echo "WaitForResources Timeout! Killing zombies...\n";
        $multi->killAllResources();
        break;
    }
}

// All process has been executed, but this does not mean they finished their work.
// This is important to follow the last executed processes to avoid zombies.
$ret = $multi->waitForTheEnd($timeout = 10, $interval = 500000);
if ($ret == false)
{
    echo "WaitForTheEnd Timeout! Killing zombies...\n";
    $multi->killAllResources();
}

// We destroy the process pool because we run all processes.
$multi->destroy();
echo "Finish.\n";
```

### And what about the process child, the simulated thread's context

A child (executed job) has only 3 things to do :

- tell the process launcher it started
- do his job
- tell the process launcher it finished

<kbd>PHP</kbd> It could contains something like this:

```
<?php
// child.php

require_once("ProcessesPool.php");

// we create the *same* instance of the process pool
$multi = new ProcessesPool($label = 'test');

// child tells the launcher it started (there will be one more resource busy in pool)
$multi->start();

// here I simulate job's execution
sleep(rand() % 5 + 1);

// child tells the launcher it finished his job (there will be one more resource free in pool)
$multi->finish();
```

### Your usage example is nice, but where is the `ProcessPool` class?

There is a lot of ways to synchronize tasks but it really depends on your requirements and constraints.

You can synchronize your tasks using :

- an unique file
- a database
- a directory and several files
- probably other methods (such as system IPCs)

As we seen already, we need at least 7 methods:

<kbd>1</kbd> `create()` will create an empty pool

<kbd>2</kbd> `start()` takes a resource on the pool

<kbd>3</kbd> `finish()` releases a resource

<kbd>4</kbd> `waitForResources()` hangs if there is no more free resource

<kbd>5</kbd> `killAllResources()` get all launched jobs in the pool and kills them

<kbd>6</kbd> `waitForTheEnd()` hangs until there is no more busy resource

<kbd>7</kbd> `destroy()` destroys pool

So let's begin by creating an abstract class, we'll be able to implement it using the above ways later.

<kbd>PHP</kbd> AbstractProcessPool.php

```
<?php

// AbstractProcessPool.php

abstract class AbstractProcessesPool
{

    abstract protected function _createPool();

    abstract protected function _cleanPool();

    abstract protected function _destroyPool();

    abstract protected function _getPoolAge();

    abstract protected function _countPid();

    abstract protected function _addPid($pid);

    abstract protected function _removePid($pid);

    abstract protected function _getPidList();

    protected $_label;
    protected $_max;
    protected $_pid;

    public function __construct($label)
    {
        $this->_max = 0;
        $this->_label = $label;
        $this->_pid = getmypid();
    }

    public function getLabel()
    {
        return ($this->_label);
    }

    public function create($max = 20)
    {
        $this->_max = $max;
        $ret = $this->_createPool();
        return $ret;
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
        $ret = $this->_destroyPool();
        return $ret;
    }

    public function waitForResource($timeout = 120, $interval = 500000, $callback = null)
    {
        // let enough time for children to take a resource
        usleep(200000);
        while (44000)
        {
            if (($callback != null) && (is_callable($callback)))
            {
                call_user_func($callback, $this);
            }
            $age = $this->_getPoolAge();
            if ($age == -1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if ($age > $timeout)
            {
                return false;
            }
            $count = $this->_countPid();
            if ($count == -1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if ($count < $this->_max)
            {
                break;
            }
            usleep($interval);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function waitForTheEnd($timeout = 3600, $interval = 500000, $callback = null)
    {
        // let enough time to the last child to take a resource
        usleep(200000);
        while (44000)
        {
            if (($callback != null) && (is_callable($callback)))
            {
                call_user_func($callback, $this);
            }
            $age = $this->_getPoolAge();
            if ($age == -1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if ($age > $timeout)
            {
                return false;
            }
            $count = $this->_countPid();
            if ($count == -1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if ($count == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            usleep($interval);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function start()
    {
        $ret = $this->_addPid($this->_pid);
        return $ret;
    }

    public function finish()
    {
        $ret = $this->_removePid($this->_pid);
        return $ret;
    }

    public function killAllResources($code = 9)
    {
        $pids = $this->_getPidList();
        if ($pids == false)
        {
            $this->_cleanPool();
            return false;
        }
        foreach ($pids as $pid)
        {
            $pid = intval($pid);
            posix_kill($pid, $code);
            if ($this->_removePid($pid) == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

#### Synchronisation using a directory and several files

If you want to use the directory method (on a `/dev/ram1` partition for example), the implementation will be :

<kbd>1</kbd> `create()` will create an empty directory using the given `$label`

<kbd>2</kbd> `start()` creates a file in the directory, named by the child's pid

<kbd>3</kbd> `finish()` destroy the child's file

<kbd>4</kbd> `waitForResources()` counts file inside that directory

<kbd>5</kbd> `killAllResources()` reads directory content and kill all pids

<kbd>6</kbd> `waitForTheEnd()` reads directory until there is no more files

<kbd>7</kbd> `destroy()` removes directory

This method looks costy, but it is really efficient if you want to run hundred tasks simultaneously without taking as many database connections as there is jobs to execute.

**Implementation** :

<kbd>PHP</kbd> ProcessPoolFiles.php

```
<?php

// ProcessPoolFiles.php

class ProcessesPoolFiles extends AbstractProcessesPool
{

    protected $_dir;

    public function __construct($label, $dir)
    {
        parent::__construct($label);
        if ((!is_dir($dir)) || (!is_writable($dir)))
        {
            throw new Exception("Directory '{$dir}' does not exist or is not writable.");
        }
        $sha1 = sha1($label);
        $this->_dir = "{$dir}/pool_{$sha1}";
    }

    protected function _createPool()
    {
        if ((!is_dir($this->_dir)) && (!mkdir($this->_dir, 0777)))
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not create '{$this->_dir}'");
        }
        if ($this->_cleanPool() == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function _cleanPool()
    {
        $dh = opendir($this->_dir);
        if ($dh == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
        {
            if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..'))
            {
                if (unlink($this->_dir . '/' . $file) == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
        return true;
    }

    protected function _destroyPool()
    {
        if ($this->_cleanPool() == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!rmdir($this->_dir))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function _getPoolAge()
    {
        $age = -1;
        $count = 0;
        $dh = opendir($this->_dir);
        if ($dh == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
        {
            if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..'))
            {
                $stat = @stat($this->_dir . '/' . $file);
                if ($stat['mtime'] > $age)
                {
                    $age = $stat['mtime'];
                }
                $count++;
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
        clearstatcache();
        return (($count > 0) ? (@time() - $age) : (0));
    }

    protected function _countPid()
    {
        $count = 0;
        $dh = opendir($this->_dir);
        if ($dh == false)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
        {
            if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..'))
            {
                $count++;
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
        return $count;
    }

    protected function _addPid($pid)
    {
        $file = $this->_dir . "/" . $pid;
        if (is_file($file))
        {
            return true;
        }
        echo "{$file}\n";
        $file = fopen($file, 'w');
        if ($file == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        fclose($file);
        return true;
    }

    protected function _removePid($pid)
    {
        $file = $this->_dir . "/" . $pid;
        if (!is_file($file))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (unlink($file) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function _getPidList()
    {
        $array = array ();
        $dh = opendir($this->_dir);
        if ($dh == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
        {
            if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..'))
            {
                $array[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
        return $array;
    }

}
```

<kbd>PHP</kbd> **demo**, the process launcher:

```
<?php

// pool_files_launcher.php

require_once("AbstractProcessesPool.php");
require_once("ProcessesPoolFiles.php");

$multi = new ProcessesPoolFiles($label = 'test', $dir = "/tmp");

if ($multi->create($max = '10') == false)
{
    echo "Pool creation failed ...\n";
    exit();
}

$count = 20;

for ($i = 0; ($i < $count); $i++)
{
    $ret = $multi->waitForResource($timeout = 10, $interval = 500000, 'test_waitForResource');
    if ($ret)
    {
        echo "Execute new process: $i\n";
        exec("/usr/bin/php ./pool_files_calc.php $i > /dev/null &");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "WaitForResources Timeout! Killing zombies...\n";
        $multi->killAllResources();
        break;
    }
}

$ret = $multi->waitForTheEnd($timeout = 10, $interval = 500000, 'test_waitForTheEnd');
if ($ret == false)
{
    echo "WaitForTheEnd Timeout! Killing zombies...\n";
    $multi->killAllResources();
}

$multi->destroy();
echo "Finish.\n";

function test_waitForResource($multi)
{
    echo "Waiting for available resource ( {$multi->getLabel()} )...\n";
}

function test_waitForTheEnd($multi)
{
    echo "Waiting for all resources to finish ( {$multi->getLabel()} )...\n";
}
```

<kbd>PHP</kbd> **demo**, the process child:

```
<?php

// pool_files_calc.php

require_once("AbstractProcessesPool.php");
require_once("ProcessesPoolFiles.php");

$multi = new ProcessesPoolFiles($label = 'test', $dir = "/tmp");

$multi->start();

// here I simulate job's execution
sleep(rand() % 7 + 1);

$multi->finish();
```

#### Synchronisation using a database

<kbd>MySQL</kbd> If you prefer using the database method, you'll need a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE `processes_pool` (
  `label` varchar(40) PRIMARY KEY,
  `nb_launched` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pid_list` varchar(2048) default NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then, the implementation will be something like:

<kbd>1</kbd> `create()` will insert a new row in the above table

<kbd>2</kbd> `start()` inserts a pid on the pid list

<kbd>3</kbd> `finish()` remove one pid from the pid list

<kbd>4</kbd> `waitForResources()` reads nb_launched field

<kbd>5</kbd> `killAllResources()` gets and kills every pid

<kbd>6</kbd> `waitForTheEnd()` hangs and checks regularily until nb_launched equals 0

<kbd>7</kbd> `destroy()` removes the row

**Implementation**:

<kbd>PHP</kbd> ProcessPoolMySql.php

```
<?php

// ProcessPoolMysql.php

class ProcessesPoolMySQL extends AbstractProcessesPool
{

    protected $_sql;

    public function __construct($label, PDO $sql)
    {
        parent::__construct($label);
        $this->_sql = $sql;
        $this->_label = sha1($label);
    }

    protected function _createPool()
    {
        $request = "
            INSERT IGNORE INTO processes_pool
            VALUES ( ?, ?, NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
        ";
        $this->_query($request, $this->_label, 0);
        return $this->_cleanPool();
    }

    protected function _cleanPool()
    {
        $request = "
            UPDATE processes_pool
            SET
                nb_launched = ?,
                pid_list = NULL,
                updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            WHERE label = ?
        ";
        $this->_query($request, 0, $this->_label);
        return true;
    }

    protected function _destroyPool()
    {
        $request = "
            DELETE FROM processes_pool
            WHERE label = ?
        ";
        $this->_query($request, $this->_label);
        return true;
    }

    protected function _getPoolAge()
    {
        $request = "
            SELECT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - updated) AS age
            FROM processes_pool
            WHERE label = ?
         ";
        $ret = $this->_query($request, $this->_label);
        if ($ret === null)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return $ret['age'];
    }

    protected function _countPid()
    {
        $req = "
            SELECT nb_launched AS nb
            FROM processes_pool
            WHERE label = ?
        ";
        $ret = $this->_query($req, $this->_label);
        if ($ret === null)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return $ret['nb'];
    }

    protected function _addPid($pid)
    {
        $request = "
            UPDATE processes_pool
            SET
                nb_launched = (nb_launched + 1),
                pid_list = CONCAT_WS(',', (SELECT IF(LENGTH(pid_list) = 0, NULL, pid_list )), ?),
                updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            WHERE label = ?
        ";
        $this->_query($request, $pid, $this->_label);
        return true;
    }

    protected function _removePid($pid)
    {
        $req = "
            UPDATE processes_pool
            SET
                nb_launched = (nb_launched - 1),
                pid_list =
                    CONCAT_WS(',', (SELECT IF (LENGTH(
                        SUBSTRING_INDEX(pid_list, ',', (FIND_IN_SET(?, pid_list) - 1))) = 0, null,
                            SUBSTRING_INDEX(pid_list, ',', (FIND_IN_SET(?, pid_list) - 1)))), (SELECT IF (LENGTH(
                                SUBSTRING_INDEX(pid_list, ',', (-1 * ((LENGTH(pid_list) - LENGTH(REPLACE(pid_list, ',', ''))) + 1 - FIND_IN_SET(?, pid_list))))) = 0, null,
                                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(pid_list, ',', (-1 * ((LENGTH(pid_list) - LENGTH(REPLACE(pid_list, ',', ''))) + 1 - FIND_IN_SET(?, pid_list))
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                 ),
                updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            WHERE label = ?";
        $this->_query($req, $pid, $pid, $pid, $pid, $this->_label);
        return true;
    }

    protected function _getPidList()
    {
        $req = "
            SELECT pid_list
            FROM processes_pool
            WHERE label = ?
        ";
        $ret = $this->_query($req, $this->_label);
        if ($ret === null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if ($ret['pid_list'] == null)
        {
            return array();
        }
        $pid_list = explode(',', $ret['pid_list']);
        return $pid_list;
    }

    protected function _query($request)
    {
        $return = null;

        $stmt = $this->_sql->prepare($request);
        if ($stmt === false)
        {
            return $return;
        }

        $params = func_get_args();
        array_shift($params);

        if ($stmt->execute($params) === false)
        {
            return $return;
        }

        if (strncasecmp(trim($request), 'SELECT', 6) === 0)
        {
            $return = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        return $return;
    }

}
```

<kbd>PHP</kbd> **demo**, the process launcher:

```
<?php

// pool_mysql_launcher.php

require_once("AbstractProcessesPool.php");
require_once("ProcessesPoolMySQL.php");

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=fuz", 'root', 'root');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$multi = new ProcessesPoolMySQL($label = 'test', $dbh);

if ($multi->create($max = '10') == false)
{
    echo "Pool creation failed ...\n";
    exit();
}

$count = 20;

for ($i = 0; ($i < $count); $i++)
{
    $ret = $multi->waitForResource($timeout = 10, $interval = 500000, 'test_waitForResource');
    if ($ret)
    {
        echo "Execute new process: $i\n";
        exec("/usr/bin/php ./pool_mysql_calc.php $i > /dev/null &");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "WaitForResources Timeout! Killing zombies...\n";
        $multi->killAllResources();
        break;
    }
}

$ret = $multi->waitForTheEnd($timeout = 10, $interval = 500000, 'test_waitForTheEnd');
if ($ret == false)
{
    echo "WaitForTheEnd Timeout! Killing zombies...\n";
    $multi->killAllResources();
}

$multi->destroy();
echo "Finish.\n";

function test_waitForResource($multi)
{
    echo "Waiting for available resource ( {$multi->getLabel()} )...\n";
}

function test_waitForTheEnd($multi)
{
    echo "Waiting for all resources to finish ( {$multi->getLabel()} )...\n";
}
```

<kbd>PHP</kbd> **demo**, the process child:

```
<?php

// pool_mysql_calc.php

require_once("AbstractProcessesPool.php");
require_once("ProcessesPoolMySQL.php");

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=fuz", 'root', 'root');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$multi = new ProcessesPoolMySQL($label = 'test', $dbh);

$multi->start();

// here I simulate job's execution
sleep(rand() % 7 + 1);

$multi->finish();
```

#### What is the output of the above code?

<kbd>Demo output</kbd> Those demo gives - fortunately - about the same output. If the timeout is not reached (the dreams's case), output is:

```
KolyMac:TaskManager ninsuo$ php pool_files_launcher.php 
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 0
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 1
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 2
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 3
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 4
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 5
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 6
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 7
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 8
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 9
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 10
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 11
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 12
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 13
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 14
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 15
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 16
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 17
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 18
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 19
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Finish.
```

<kbd>Demo output</kbd> In a worse case (I change `sleep(rand() % 7 + 1);` to `sleep(rand() % 7 + 100);`, this gives:

```
KolyMac:TaskManager ninsuo$ php pool_files_launcher.php 
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 0
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 1
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 2
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 3
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 4
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 5
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 6
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 7
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 8
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Execute new process: 9
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
(...)
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
Waiting for available resource ( test )...
WaitForResources Timeout! Killing zombies...
Waiting for all resources to finish ( test )...
Finish.
```

Go to [page 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595721/731138) to continue reading this answer.

Comment: Hey really thanks for the detailed mutex decription, I actually built my own simple process control in my [framework](https://github.com/victopia/php-node) (documentations awaits). While you are making something very constructive to the community, please complete what you are doing. I'll be reading as you go. ;)

Comment: One of the best answers I've seen on here. Thank you. This has saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 5):

**Page 2**: there is a limit for SO answer's body to 30k chars, so I need to create a new one.

---

## Keep control on results

[image: No mistake allowd]

### No mistake allowed!

**YEAH !** You can launch tons of processes without taking care of resources. But what if one child process fails? There will be one undone or incomplete job!...

In fact, this is simpler (far simpler) than controlling process execution. We have a queue of jobs executed using a pool, and we only need to know if one has failed or succeded after its execution. If there is failure when the whole pool is executed, then failed processes are put on a new pool, and are executed again.

[image: Result control]

### How to proceed in PHP ?

This principle is based on clusters: queue contains several jobs, but represents only one entity. Each calcul of the cluster
should succeed to get that entity complete.

Roadmap:

<kbd>1</kbd> We create a todo list (to mismatch with the *queue*, used for process management) containing all *calculs* of the cluster.  Each job has a status: waiting (not executed), running (executed and not finished), success and error (according to their result), and of course, at this step, their status is WAITING.

<kbd>2</kbd> We run all jobs using the process manager (to keep control on resources), each one begin by telling the task manager it *runs*, and according to his own context, it finishes by indicating his state (failed or success).

<kbd>3</kbd> When the entire queue is executed, the task manager creates a new queue with failed jobs, and loops again.

<kbd>4</kbd> When all jobs succeed, you're done, and you're sure nothing went wrong. Your cluster is complete and your entity usable at upper level.

### Proof of concept

There is nothing more to tell about the subject, so let's write some code, continuing the previous sample code.

As for process management, you can use several ways to synchronize your parents and children, but there is no *hard* logic, so there is no need for an abstraction.
So I developped a MySQL example (faster to write), you'll be free to adapt this concept for your requirements and constraints.

<kbd>MySQL</kbd> Create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks_manager` (
  `cluster_label` varchar(40),
  `calcul_label` varchar(40),
  `status` enum('waiting', 'running', 'failed', 'success') default 'waiting',
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`cluster_label`, `calcul_label`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

<kbd>PHP</kbd> Here is the `TaskManager.php` file:

```
<?php

class TasksManager
{

    protected $_cluster_label;
    protected $_calcul_label;
    protected $_sql;

    const WAITING = "waiting";
    const RUNNING = "running";
    const SUCCESS = "success";
    const FAILED = "failed";

    public function __construct($label, PDO $sql)
    {
        $this->_sql = $sql;
        $this->_cluster_label = substr($label, 0, 40);
    }

    public function getClusterLabel()
    {
        return $this->_cluster_label;
    }

    public function getCalculLabel()
    {
        return $this->_calcul_label;
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
        $request = "
            DELETE FROM tasks_manager
            WHERE cluster_label = ?
        ";
        $this->_query($request, $this->_cluster_label);
        return $this;
    }

    public function start($calcul_label)
    {
        $this->_calcul_label = $calcul_label;
        $this->add($calcul_label, TasksManager::RUNNING);
        return $this;
    }

    public function finish($status = TasksManager::SUCCESS)
    {
        if (!$this->_isStatus($status))
        {
            throw new Exception("{$status} is not a valid status.");
        }
        if (is_null($this->_cluster_label))
        {
            throw new Exception("finish() called, but task never started.");
        }
        $request = "
            UPDATE tasks_manager
            SET status = ?
            WHERE cluster_label = ?
            AND calcul_label = ?
         ";
        $this->_query($request, $status, $this->_cluster_label, substr($this->_calcul_label, 0, 40));
        return $this;
    }

    public function add($calcul_label, $status = TasksManager::WAITING)
    {
        if (!$this->_isStatus($status))
        {
            throw new Exception("{$status} is not a valid status.");
        }
        $request = "
            INSERT INTO tasks_manager (
                cluster_label, calcul_label, status
            ) VALUES (
                ?, ?, ?
            )
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                status = ?
        ";
        $calcul_label = substr($calcul_label, 0, 40);
        $this->_query($request, $this->_cluster_label, $calcul_label, $status, $status);
        return $this;
    }

    public function delete($calcul_label)
    {
        $request = "
            DELETE FROM tasks_manager
            WHERE cluster_label = ?
            AND calcul_label = ?
        ";
        $this->_query($request, $this->_cluster_label, substr($calcul_label, 0, 40));
        return $this;
    }

    public function countStatus($status = TasksManager::SUCCESS)
    {
        if (!$this->_isStatus($status))
        {
            throw new Exception("{$status} is not a valid status.");
        }
        $request = "
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
            FROM tasks_manager
            WHERE cluster_label = ?
            AND status = ?
        ";
        $ret = $this->_query($request, $this->_cluster_label, $status);
        return $ret[0]['cnt'];
    }

    public function count()
    {
        $request = "
            SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt
            FROM tasks_manager
            WHERE cluster_label = ?
        ";
        $ret = $this->_query($request, $this->_cluster_label);
        return $ret[0]['cnt'];
    }

    public function getCalculsByStatus($status = TasksManager::SUCCESS)
    {
        if (!$this->_isStatus($status))
        {
            throw new Exception("{$status} is not a valid status.");
        }
        $request = "
            SELECT calcul_label
            FROM tasks_manager
            WHERE cluster_label = ?
            AND status = ?
        ";
        $ret = $this->_query($request, $this->_cluster_label, $status);
        $array = array();
        if (!is_null($ret))
        {
            $array = array_map(function($row) {
                return $row['calcul_label'];
            }, $ret);
        }
        return $array;
    }

    public function switchStatus($statusA = TasksManager::RUNNING, $statusB = null)
    {
        if (!$this->_isStatus($statusA))
        {
            throw new Exception("{$statusA} is not a valid status.");
        }
        if ((!is_null($statusB)) && (!$this->_isStatus($statusB)))
        {
            throw new Exception("{$statusB} is not a valid status.");
        }
        if ($statusB != null)
        {
            $request = "
                UPDATE tasks_manager
                SET status = ?
                WHERE cluster_label = ?
                AND status = ?
            ";
            $this->_query($request, $statusB, $this->_cluster_label, $statusA);
        }
        else
        {
            $request = "
                UPDATE tasks_manager
                SET status = ?
                WHERE cluster_label = ?
            ";
            $this->_query($request, $statusA, $this->_cluster_label);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    private function _isStatus($status)
    {
        if (!is_string($status))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return in_array($status, array(
                self::FAILED,
                self::RUNNING,
                self::SUCCESS,
                self::WAITING,
        ));
    }

    protected function _query($request)
    {
        $return = null;

        $stmt = $this->_sql->prepare($request);
        if ($stmt === false)
        {
            return $return;
        }

        $params = func_get_args();
        array_shift($params);

        if ($stmt->execute($params) === false)
        {
            return $return;
        }

        if (strncasecmp(trim($request), 'SELECT', 6) === 0)
        {
            $return = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        return $return;
    }

}
```

<kbd>PHP</kbd> The `task_launcher.php` is the usage example

```
<?php

require_once("AbstractProcessesPool.php");
require_once("ProcessesPoolMySQL.php");
require_once("TasksManager.php");

// Initializing database connection
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=fuz", 'root', 'root');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Initializing process pool
$pool = new ProcessesPoolMySQL($label = "pool test", $dbh);
$pool->create($max = "10");

// Initializing task manager
$multi = new TasksManager($label = "jobs test", $dbh);
$multi->destroy();

// Simulating jobs
$count = 20;
$todo_list = array ();
for ($i = 0; ($i < $count); $i++)
{
    $todo_list[$i] = "Job {$i}";
    $multi->add($todo_list[$i], TasksManager::WAITING);
}

// Infinite loop until all jobs are done
$continue = true;
while ($continue)
{
    $continue = false;

    echo "Starting to run jobs in queue ...\n";

    // put all failed jobs to WAITING status
    $multi->switchStatus(TasksManager::FAILED, TasksManager::WAITING);

    foreach ($todo_list as $job)
    {

        $ret = $pool->waitForResource($timeout = 10, $interval = 500000, "waitResource");

        if ($ret)
        {
            echo "Executing job: $job\n";
            exec(sprintf("/usr/bin/php ./tasks_program.php %s > /dev/null &", escapeshellarg($job)));
        }
        else
        {
            echo "waitForResource timeout!\n";
            $pool->killAllResources();

            // All jobs currently running are considered dead, so, failed
            $multi->switchStatus(TasksManager::RUNNING, TasksManager::FAILED);

            break;
        }
    }

    $ret = $pool->waitForTheEnd($timeout = 10, $interval = 500000, "waitEnd");
    if ($ret == false)
    {
        echo "waitForTheEnd timeout!\n";
        $pool->killAllResources();

        // All jobs currently running are considered dead, so, failed
        $multi->switchStatus(TasksManager::RUNNING, TasksManager::FAILED);
    }


    echo "All jobs in queue executed, looking for errors...\n";

    // Counts if there is failures
    $nb_failed = $multi->countStatus(TasksManager::FAILED);
    if ($nb_failed > 0)
    {
        $todo_list = $multi->getCalculsByStatus(TasksManager::FAILED);
        echo sprintf("%d jobs failed: %s\n", $nb_failed, implode(', ', $todo_list));
        $continue = true;
    }
}

function waitResource($multi)
{
    echo "Waiting for a resource ....\n";
}

function waitEnd($multi)
{
    echo "Waiting for the end .....\n";
}

// All jobs finished, destroying task manager
$multi->destroy();

// Destroying process pool
$pool->destroy();

echo "Finish.\n";
```

<kbd>PHP</kbd> And here is the child program (a calcul)

```
<?php

if (!isset($argv[1]))
{
    die("This program must be called with an identifier (calcul_label)\n");
}
$calcul_label = $argv[1];

require_once("AbstractProcessesPool.php");
require_once("ProcessesPoolMySQL.php");
require_once("TasksManager.php");

// Initializing database connection
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=fuz", 'root', 'root');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Initializing process pool (with same label as parent)
$pool = new ProcessesPoolMySQL($label = "pool test", $dbh);

// Takes one resource in pool
$pool->start();

// Initializing task manager (with same label as parent)
$multi = new TasksManager($label = "jobs test", $dbh);
$multi->start($calcul_label);

// Simulating execution time
$secs = (rand() % 2) + 3;
sleep($secs);

// Simulating job status
$status = rand() % 3 == 0 ? TasksManager::FAILED : TasksManager::SUCCESS;

// Job finishes indicating his status
$multi->finish($status);

// Releasing pool's resource
$pool->finish();
```

<kbd>Demo output</kbd> This demo will give you something [like this](http://pastebin.com/emQEgT7T) (too large for SO).

---

## Synchronization and communication between processes

[image: A sample of communication error]

### There is solutions to communicate easily without errors.

#### Take a coffee, we're close to the end!

We are now able to launch tons of processes and they are all giving the expected result, well, this is not bad.
But now, all our processes are executed stand-alone, and they actually can't communicate each others. That is your
core problem, and there is a lot of solutions.

It is really difficult to tell you exactly what kind of communication you need. You were speaking about what you tried (IPCs, 
communication using files, or home-made protocols), but not what kind of information are shared between your processes.
Anyway, I invite you to think about an OOP solution.

### PHP is powerful.

PHP has [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) :

- `__get($property)` let us implement the access of a `$property` on an object
- `__set($property, $value)` let us implement the assignation of a `$property` on an object

PHP can handle files, with concurrent-access management

- `fopen($file, 'c+')` opens a file with advisory lock options enabled (allow you to use [flock](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php))
- `flock($descriptor, LOCK_SH)` takes a shared lock (for reading)
- `flock($descriptor, LOCK_EX)` takes an exclusive lock (for writting)

Finally, PHP has:

- `json_encode($object)` to get a json representation of an object
- `json_decode($string)` to get back an object from a json string

You see where I'm going? We will create a `Synchro` class that will work the same way as the `stdClass` class, but it will be always safely synchronized on a file. Our processes will be able to access the same instance of that object at the *same* time.

### Some Linux systems tricks

Of course, if you have 150 processes working on the same file at the same time, your hard drive will slow down your processes. To
handle this issue, why not creating a filesystem partition on RAM? Writing into that file will be about as quick as writing
in memory!

<kbd>shell</kbd> As root, type the following commands:

```
mkfs -q /dev/ram1 65536
mkdir -p /ram
mount /dev/ram1 /ram
```

Some notes :

- 65536 is in kilobytes, here you get a 64M partition.
- if you want to mount that partition at startup, create a shell script and call it inside `/etc/rc.local` file.

### Implementation

<kbd>PHP</kbd> Here is the `Synchro.php` class.

```
<?php

class Synchro
{

   private $_file;

   public function __construct($file)
   {
       $this->_file = $file;
   }

   public function __get($property)
   {
       // File does not exist
       if (!is_file($this->_file))
       {
           return null;
       }

       // Check if file is readable
       if ((is_file($this->_file)) && (!is_readable($this->_file)))
       {
           throw new Exception(sprintf("File '%s' is not readable.", $this->_file));
       }

       // Open file with advisory lock option enabled for reading and writting
       if (($fd = fopen($this->_file, 'c+')) === false)
       {
           throw new Exception(sprintf("Can't open '%s' file.", $this->_file));
       }

       // Request a lock for reading (hangs until lock is granted successfully)
       if (flock($fd, LOCK_SH) === false)
       {
           throw new Exception(sprintf("Can't lock '%s' file for reading.", $this->_file));
       }

       // A hand-made file_get_contents
       $contents = '';
       while (($read = fread($fd, 32 * 1024)) !== '')
       {
           $contents .= $read;
       }

       // Release shared lock and close file
       flock($fd, LOCK_UN);
       fclose($fd);

       // Restore shared data object and return requested property
       $object = json_decode($contents);
       if (property_exists($object, $property))
       {
           return $object->{$property};
       }

       return null;
   }

   public function __set($property, $value)
   {
       // Check if directory is writable if file does not exist
       if ((!is_file($this->_file)) && (!is_writable(dirname($this->_file))))
       {
           throw new Exception(sprintf("Directory '%s' does not exist or is not writable.", dirname($this->_file)));
       }

       // Check if file is writable if it exists
       if ((is_file($this->_file)) && (!is_writable($this->_file)))
       {
           throw new Exception(sprintf("File '%s' is not writable.", $this->_file));
       }

       // Open file with advisory lock option enabled for reading and writting
       if (($fd = fopen($this->_file, 'c+')) === false)
       {
           throw new Exception(sprintf("Can't open '%s' file.", $this->_file));
       }

       // Request a lock for writting (hangs until lock is granted successfully)
       if (flock($fd, LOCK_EX) === false)
       {
           throw new Exception(sprintf("Can't lock '%s' file for writing.", $this->_file));
       }

       // A hand-made file_get_contents
       $contents = '';
       while (($read = fread($fd, 32 * 1024)) !== '')
       {
           $contents .= $read;
       }

       // Restore shared data object and set value for desired property
       if (empty($contents))
       {
           $object = new stdClass();
       }
       else
       {
           $object = json_decode($contents);
       }
       $object->{$property} = $value;

       // Go back at the beginning of file
       rewind($fd);

       // Truncate file
       ftruncate($fd, strlen($contents));

       // Save shared data object to the file
       fwrite($fd, json_encode($object));

       // Release exclusive lock and close file
       flock($fd, LOCK_UN);
       fclose($fd);

       return $value;
   }

}
```

### Demonstration

We will continue (and finish) our processes / tasks example by making our processes communicate each others.

Rules :

- Our goal is to get the sum of all numbers between 1 and 20.
- We have 20 processes, with ID from 1 to 20.
- Those processes are randomly queued for execution.
- Each process (except process 1) can do only one calculation : its id + the previous process's result
- Process 1 directly put his id
- Each process succeed if it can do his calculation (means, if the previous process's result is available), else it fails (and is candidate for a new queue)
- The pool's timeout expires after 10 seconds

Well, it looks complicated but actually, it is a good representation of what you'll find in a real-life situation.

<kbd>PHP</kbd>  `synchro_launcher.php` file.

```
<?php

require_once("AbstractProcessesPool.php");
require_once("ProcessesPoolMySQL.php");
require_once("TasksManager.php");
require_once("Synchro.php");

// Removing old synchroized object
if (is_file("/tmp/synchro.txt"))
{
    unlink("/tmp/synchro.txt");
}

// Initializing database connection
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=fuz", 'root', 'root');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Initializing process pool
$pool = new ProcessesPoolMySQL($label = "synchro pool", $dbh);
$pool->create($max = "10");

// Initializing task manager
$multi = new TasksManager($label = "synchro tasks", $dbh);
$multi->destroy();

// Simulating jobs
$todo_list = array ();
for ($i = 1; ($i <= 20); $i++)
{
    $todo_list[$i] = $i;
    $multi->add($todo_list[$i], TasksManager::WAITING);
}

// Infinite loop until all jobs are done
$continue = true;
while ($continue)
{
    $continue = false;

    echo "Starting to run jobs in queue ...\n";

    // Shuffle all jobs (else this will be too easy :-))
    shuffle($todo_list);

    // put all failed jobs to WAITING status
    $multi->switchStatus(TasksManager::FAILED, TasksManager::WAITING);

    foreach ($todo_list as $job)
    {

        $ret = $pool->waitForResource($timeout = 10, $interval = 500000, "waitResource");

        if ($ret)
        {
            echo "Executing job: $job\n";
            exec(sprintf("/usr/bin/php ./synchro_program.php %s > /dev/null &", escapeshellarg($job)));
        }
        else
        {
            echo "waitForResource timeout!\n";
            $pool->killAllResources();

            // All jobs currently running are considered dead, so, failed
            $multi->switchStatus(TasksManager::RUNNING, TasksManager::FAILED);

            break;
        }
    }

    $ret = $pool->waitForTheEnd($timeout = 10, $interval = 500000, "waitEnd");
    if ($ret == false)
    {
        echo "waitForTheEnd timeout!\n";
        $pool->killAllResources();

        // All jobs currently running are considered dead, so, failed
        $multi->switchStatus(TasksManager::RUNNING, TasksManager::FAILED);
    }


    echo "All jobs in queue executed, looking for errors...\n";

    // Counts if there is failures
    $multi->switchStatus(TasksManager::WAITING, TasksManager::FAILED);
    $nb_failed = $multi->countStatus(TasksManager::FAILED);
    if ($nb_failed > 0)
    {
        $todo_list = $multi->getCalculsByStatus(TasksManager::FAILED);
        echo sprintf("%d jobs failed: %s\n", $nb_failed, implode(', ', $todo_list));
        $continue = true;
    }
}

function waitResource($multi)
{
    echo "Waiting for a resource ....\n";
}

function waitEnd($multi)
{
    echo "Waiting for the end .....\n";
}

// All jobs finished, destroying task manager
$multi->destroy();

// Destroying process pool
$pool->destroy();

// Recovering final result
$synchro = new Synchro("/tmp/synchro.txt");
echo sprintf("Result of the sum of all numbers between 1 and 20 included is: %d\n", $synchro->result20);

echo "Finish.\n";
```

<kbd>PHP</kbd> And its associed `synchro_calcul.php` file.

```
<?php

if (!isset($argv[1]))
{
   die("This program must be called with an identifier (calcul_label)\n");
}
$current_id = $argv[1];

require_once("AbstractProcessesPool.php");
require_once("ProcessesPoolMySQL.php");
require_once("TasksManager.php");
require_once("Synchro.php");

// Initializing database connection
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=fuz", 'root', 'root');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Initializing process pool (with same label as parent)
$pool = new ProcessesPoolMySQL($label = "synchro pool", $dbh);

// Takes one resource in pool
$pool->start();

// Initializing task manager (with same label as parent)
$multi = new TasksManager($label = "synchro tasks", $dbh);
$multi->start($current_id);

// ------------------------------------------------------
// Job begins here

$synchro = new Synchro("/tmp/synchro.txt");

if ($current_id == 1)
{
   $synchro->result1 = 1;
   $status = TasksManager::SUCCESS;
}
else
{
   $previous_id = $current_id - 1;
   if (is_null($synchro->{"result{$previous_id}"}))
   {
       $status = TasksManager::FAILED;
   }
   else
   {
       $synchro->{"result{$current_id}"} = $synchro->{"result{$previous_id}"} + $current_id;
       $status = TasksManager::SUCCESS;
   }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------

// Job finishes indicating his status
$multi->finish($status);

// Releasing pool's resource
$pool->finish();
```

### Output

The following demo will give you something like [this output](http://pastebin.com/j3MjaVfr) (too large for SO)

---

## Conclusion

Task management in PHP is not really easy because of the missing threads. As many developers, I hope this feature will come
built-in someday. Anyway, this is possible to control resources and results, and to share data between processes, so we can do,
with some work I assume, task management efficiently.

Synchronization and communication can be done by several ways, but you need to check out pros and cons for each one, according
to your constraints and requirements. For example:

- if you need to launch 500 tasks at once and want to use a MySQL synchronization method, you'll need 1+500 simultaneous connections to the database (it may not appreciate a lot).
- If you need to share a big amount of data, using only one file may be inefficient.
- If you are using file for synchronization, don't forget to have a look to system built-in tools such as `/dev/sdram`.
- Try to stay as more as possible in an object-oriented programming to handle your troubles. Home-made protocols or such will make your app harder to maintain.

I gave you my 2-cents about this interesting subject, and I hope it will give you some ideas to solve your issues.

Comment: After reading this it turns out that I should queue the processes in a lower level, like http requests, or at least let the spawned tasks generate them.

Comment: The framework I am currently working on in fact utilizes the database method you mentioned, but this is more of a theoretical thing than technical skills.

Thanks a lot for giving the whole picture, I could never figure out the starting point of my solution without this.

Comment: You're welcome. Multi tasking is not an easy job, but it is still really interesting, so I'm happy to share my knowledge about the subject. Good luck for your implementation :)

Comment: For those interested by the synchronization between processes, this post leaded to [a clean php class](https://github.com/Ninsuo/php-shared-memory/).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you take a look at this library called **PHP-Queue**: https://github.com/CoderKungfu/php-queue

An short description from its github page:

> A unified front-end for different queuing backends. Includes a REST
>   server, CLI interface and daemon runners.

Check out its github page for more details.

With a bit of tinkering, I think this library will help you solve your problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: interesting cluster thing, unfortunately my framework already occupied the autoloader which this library also wants to use, I could study it's IPC method instead. Thanks for sharing.